# RDS innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit problem

Tags: mysql, innodb, aws, amazon-rds

I use Amazon RDS as mysql db backend for highload project and try to optimize insert performance for innodb tables.
According to information from different sources - good candidate to speed up inserts is `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` parameter.
My local tests show significant boost when I set it to 2 (or 0), but changing this param on RDS has no effect.
What may be a problem?
I tried all available values and results are the same (30-40 inserts per second into empty table) while local tests show ~9000 inserts per second.
I also tried M3.large General Purpose SSD RDS test instance (0 load) with same result.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16968/innodb-flush-settings-on-amazon-rds

Answer (score 1):

Complain to RDS.

Meanwhile...

Plan A:  Design code to gather the rows up and do a multi-row `INSERT` or `LOAD DATA`.

Plan B:  Put `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` around small batches of rows.  (Suggest 1 second or 100 rows or 1MB, whichever comes first.)

Comment: Only 100 rows? For a big import we did on a live server the 100k value seemed to give the most performance. Sure the table itself was otherwise inactive, the server quite idle and the rows short.. But 1000x less sounds very conservative.

Comment: Yeah, 100 may be too conservative.  However, large numbers lead to slowdowns because of the undo log and/or the replication delays.

Comment: Thanks. I usually suggest to test it with 1000 when asked but I would not want to give bad advices.

Comment: 100K _rows_ is likely to blow out the undo log and cause replication stalls.  100KB for batch insert size is arguably unnecessarily small (think packet, buffer, etc sizes).

Comment: My experiments with batched `INSERT` show that 1000 rows runs at about 99% of the theoretical max speed.  Going beyond that is "diminishing returns" (and could lead to degradation, as I mentioned.)  My conservative "100" is about 90% of max; I think of it as a "safe" tradeoff.

Comment: 100K rows was really a one time instance when importing 120GB table (one row was something like 180B), which seemed to work fastest from quick testing (Galera cluster, maybe in that case the optimum is a bit shifted), but yes, I was a bit afraid about the undo logs so we monitored it and hopefully will not have to repeat on a live system again. Thank you for explaining the numbers, I am going to suggest smaller batches in the future.